# Is empty string value generally allowed by the FIX protocol?

Tags: fix-protocol

When I look at the definition of a String type in the FIX protocol (e.g. [here](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/latest/index.html#String) or [here](https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#fix-tagvalue-datatypes)), I don't see a minimum length specified. Is it allowed to use empty strings? One [online decoder](https://drewnoakes.com/fix-decoder/#base64:OD1GSVhULjEuMXxTT0h8OT02NnxTT0h8MzU9eHxTT0h8MzQ9MnxTT0h8NDk9Zm9vfFNPSHw1Mj0yMDIxMDkwNy0xMTo0Mjo0MS40Njh8U09IfDU2PWJhcnxTT0h8MjYzPTB8U09IfDMyMD18U09IfDU1OT00fFNPSHwxMD0yMjF8U09IfA==) seems to accept an empty string value (see tag 320), an [other](https://www.fixdecoding.org/) complains that it's invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIX 4.4 specification states the following (emphasis in the original text):

> Each message is constructed of a stream of `<tag>=<value>` fields with a
> field delimiter between fields in the stream. Tags are of data type
> *TagNum*. **All tags must have a value specified. Optional fields without
> values should simply not be specified in the FIX message. A Reject
> message is the appropriate response to a tag with no value.**

That strongly suggests (but does not unambiguously state) to me that the use of an empty value for a string is invalid. It is unsurprising to me that different FIX implementations might treat this edge case in different ways. So, I think the best approach is to avoid using empty values for strings.

Comment: For what it's worth, the various QuickFIX ports have a setting `ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N` which will allow empty values (e.g. "|200=|") to be received.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Ciaran's and Grant's answer/comments. Just want to add something.

1. I generally suggest to look up things like this in the **most current specification** since they usually have been refined/reworded/clarified to eliminate unclear or ambiguous statements from older specs.
2. The answer is on the very page you link to in your question (emphasis mine):
   https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#well-formed-field

> A well-formed field has the form:
>
> `tag=value<SOH>`
>
> A field shall be considered malformed if any of the following occurs as a result of encoding:
>
> the tag is empty
>
> the tag delimiter is missing
>
> **the value is empty**
>
> the value contains an `<SOH>` character and the datatype of the field is not data or XMLdata
>
> the datatype of the field is data and the field is not immediately preceded by its associated Length field.

Comment: Thanks for providing the extra information.